# Nuxt generate says page could not be found

Tags: routes, nuxt.js, contentful

I am having issues with generate.
It's saying

```
Error generating route "/": This page could not be found
```

On multiple pages, even on some pages that used to work at one point.

In my nuxt.config i have set target: "static",
SSR is set to true,
my generate looks like this:

```js
generate: {
  fallback: true,
  cache: false,
  routes: async () => await generate(),
},
```

I don't understand what the problem is, I have searched around, but all I could find was something about dynamic routes, and I don't see how that is applicable.

I Have a CMS, Contentful, which I use for my content.

Can anyone point me in a direction where I can look for a solution?

Comment: Hi, did you read [this one](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-with-a-callback)?

Comment: yep, read through that as well.

Comment: Alright, so what is not working? Also, what is `generate()`?

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or a github link?

Comment: It's almost impossible to create a minimal reproducible example.. But I did find out that for some reason Contentful sometimes don't send all published pages to me, so they have to be republished. So i'm writing them to see if they have a solution.

Comment: Not sure why this would be impossible tbh. It takes **some** effort, indeed.